# tflearn multi layer perceptron with unexpected prediction

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, neural-network, regression, tflearn

I would like to rebuild a MLP I implemented first with scikit-learn's MLPRegressor with tflearn.

sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor implementation:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv', delimiter = ';', decimal = ',', header = 0)
test_data = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', delimiter = ';', decimal = ',', header = 0)

X_train = np.array(train_data.drop(['output'], 1))
X_scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = X_scaler.transform(X_train)

Y_train = np.array(train_data['output'])

clf = MLPRegressor(activation = 'tanh', solver='lbfgs', alpha=0.0001, hidden_layer_sizes=(3))
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
prediction = clf.predict(X_train)
```

The model worked and I got an accuracy of `0.85`. Now I would like to build a similar MLP with tflearn. I started with the following code:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('train_data.csv', delimiter = ';', decimal = ',', header = 0)
test_data = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', delimiter = ';', decimal = ',', header = 0)

X_train = np.array(train_data.drop(['output'], 1))
X_scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = X_scaler.transform(X_train)

Y_train = np.array(train_data['output'])
Y_scaler = StandardScaler()
Y_scaler.fit(Y_train)
Y_train = Y_scaler.transform(Y_train.reshape((-1,1)))

net = tfl.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
net = tfl.fully_connected(net, 3, activation='tanh')
net = tfl.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='sigmoid')
net = tfl.regression(net, optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_square', learning_rate=3.)

clf = tfl.DNN(net)
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train, n_epoch=200, show_metric=True)
prediction = clf.predict(X_train)
```

At some point I definitely configured something the wrong way because the prediction is way off. The range of Y_train is between `20` and `88` and the prediction shows numbers around `0.005`. In the tflearn documentation I just found examples for classification.

### UPDATE 1:

I realized that the regression layer uses by default `'categorical_crossentropy'` as loss-function which is for classification problems. So I selected `'mean_square'` instead. I also tried to normalize `Y_train`. The prediction still not even matches the range of `Y_train`. Any thoughts?

### FINAL UPDATE:

Take a look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple of actually really dumb mistakes.

First of all I scalled the output to the interval `0` to `1` but used in the output-layer the activatuion function `tanh` which delivers values from `-1` to `1`. So I had to use either an activation function that outputs values between `0` and `1` (like e.g. `sigmoid`) or `linear` without any scaling applied.

Secondly and most importantly, for my data I chose a pretty bad combination for `learning rate` and `n_epoch`. I didn't specify any learning rate and the default one is `0.1`, I think. In any case it was too small (I end up using `3.0`). At the same time the epoch count (`10`) was also far too small, with `200` it worked fine.

I also explicitly chose `sgd` as `optimizer` (default: `adam`), which turned out to work a lot better.

I updated the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

One step should be not to scale the output.
I am also working on regression problem and I scale only the inputs and it work fine with some neural networks. Although if I use tflearn I get wrong predictions.